# Chart for distribution function

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I need a chart to represent something like the following picture in an Angular app:

[image]

The values to determine that chart are:

[image]

where `a` is the minimun value, `b` is the maximum value and `c` is the most likely value.

To display the percentage in the top part, we mark the percentage permanently 5% and 95%. The cut points must be calculated on the `x` axis

`a <= x <= b`

Accumulated probability function = 
[image]

Given an accumulated probability `p = 0.05` and `p = 0.95`, we solve the `x`:

```
If  p < =   (c-a) / (b-a)
x = a+ √ p* (b-a) * (c-a)

If  p > (c-a) / (b-a)
x = b- √ (1-p * (b-a)* (b-c)
```

If there isn't any library to represent it, what would be a way to do it?